# Using 32768KiB of shared memory for nchan in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:71

Tags: nginx

On starting nginx service got:

```
 * Starting nginx nginx                                               [ OK ]
```

ON log file "/var/log/nginx/error.log" got:

```
2018/05/03 14:05:49 [info] 5257#5257: Using 32768KiB of shared memory for nchan in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:71
```

and nginx service haven't start yet.

How to fix this?

Comment: Do you need 'nchan'? If not you can disable this module by deleting symbolic link `/path/to/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-nchan.conf` or similar.